# Jpa @Convert not being applied?

Tags: hibernate, scala, jpa

I have a simple Scala case class whit some JPA annotations and one problematic field below:

```
case class Category(...,
@(OneToMany @field)
@(Convert @field)(converter = classOf[SubcategoriesConverter])
subcategories: List[Subcategory],...
```

and the converter in question:

```
@Converter
class SubcategoriesConverter extends AttributeConverter[List[Subcategory], Collection[Subcategory]] {
  override def convertToDatabaseColumn(list: List[Subcategory]): Collection[Subcategory] = list
  override def convertToEntityAttribute(list: Collection[Subcategory]): List[Subcategory] = list.asScala.toList
```

that converts Scala List to Java Collection. The thing compiles fine, but on runtime it seems that converter is not applied since Hibernate 5.0.1 throws:

```
Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements
```

I know I can do it by using Collection insted of List as field, but if someone has bumped into something like this and has some sweet solution that would be much appreciated.

Cheers